# Verilog display reg value based on fraction length

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl, fixed-point

Say you have a signed 32bit number with a fraction length of 16bits. That is, the first 16 MSB are the integer part and the rest ( 16 LSB) are the fraction part. Is there a way in verilog to display this number number in base 10 that makes it easier to read decimals.

For example:

> 0000 0000 0000 0001 1000 0000 0000 0000 should be displayed as 1.5

I'm using Xillinx. I have looked online and I have not found a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$itor` integer to real to cast your binary pattern (integer). and use `2.0` (a real, not 2 an integer) to the power of (`**`) -16, the number of fractional bits:

```
module tb;
  initial begin
    $display("%g",$itor(32'b01_1000000000000000) * 2.0**-16);
  end
endmodule
```

On [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/92X).

Comment: Thanks. Is there away to do that using monitor? Because when I use display in my testbench I get a value of 0. Even if I set a wait 30ns then display the value is zero. Only when I use monitor  I get 0 then the expected value.

Comment: @user3697625 can you show your testbench, or minimal example which shows the problem. I do not think the problem is with `$display()` $monitor triggers when ever a value changes so it is likely that the display it not being requested at a time when the value is valid.

Comment: :I have the test code on another questin that I'm awaiting an answer for: There is use $monitor() but if i switch to $display() i get a zero. Here is the link to the question and test bench:: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35735806/ways-to-implement-recipricals-on-verilog/35767951#35767951)